# How to set "When Conditions" in C# application

Tags: premake

I'm trying to convert an existing C# to premake.  I'm using premake5 alpha 6. In my C# project, there are "When conditions" that set the reference include depending on the build configuration if it's release|x86, Debug|x86..etc.  How do I set the When Condition= in premake?

In my existing project file:

```
<When Condition=" ('$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' Or ('$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86')  ">
      <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="Project_v100">
          <HintPath>..\..\bin\x86\Project_v100.dll</HintPath>
        </Reference>
      </ItemGroup>
</When>
```

I know that if i do this in premake the result will be something like the below.

In Premake:

```
links "Project_v100.dll"
```

In project file:

```
<Reference Include="Project_v100">
      <HintPath>..\..\bin\x86\Project_v100.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're looking for `filter` : https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/filter

Answer (score 0):

More specifically:

```
filter "configurations:Release"
   links "Project_v100"
```

Here is the [user guide page on filters](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/filter), and as Citron already mentioned, the [reference manual page](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/filter).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried setting filter but it is not working. I've tried setting: 

    filter "configurations:Release"
    links "Project_v100" 
  
    filter "configurations:Debug"
    links "Projectd_v100" 

The result is   <Reference Include="Projectd_v100" /> in my C# .csproj file. It doesn't seem to be taking the "configurations:Release" into account.